# How to remove user timings or events

Tags: pagespeed

I am trying to remove some entries from my user timings under

> Behavior->Site Speed->User Timings.

Putting them there with `ga('event','timing_complete',args)` is easy, but I cannot find documentation on how to remove them.

Any help is appreciated.